# Reading and Batching Sequence data in Tensorflow with TFRecords

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, batch-processing

Hi I am currently trying to batch images of variable width with tensorflow. 
For instance i am dealing with images of size `50*245, 50*235, 50*265...and so on`

I followed a basic pipeline that i found online, first i serialize my data and write it in my tfrecord file using `tf.train.SequenceExample().` I store different widths of images, in my case `245, 235, 265 ...and so on` and my pixel data using this code.

```
    example=tf.train.SequenceExample()

    #First we store our image width in 'input_length' feature
    example.context.feature['input_length'].int64_list.value.append(sequence_length)

    feature_input=example.feature_lists.feature_list['input']

    #Then we store pixel values in 'input' feature (our sequential data)
    for pixel in image : 
        feature_input.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(pixel)

    #write in the TFRecord file
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Then we open our TFRecord file and specify parsing of our sequential data

```
#Definition of data parsing
context_features = {
            'input_length':tf.FixedLenFeature([],dtype=tf.int64)
}
sequence_features = {
            "input":tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([50,],dtype=tf.int64,allow_missing=False),

}
#Now we parse the examples
length_parsed,sequence_parsed=tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
    serialized=serialized_data,
    context_features=context_features,
    sequence_features=sequence_features
)


input_lengths,input_data=tf.train.batch(
    tensors=[length_parsed['input_length'],sequence_parsed['input']],
    batch_size=1,
    dynamic_pad=True    
)
```

The problem is that dynamic padding does not seem to work i get tensors of shape
`(?,50)` when i thought i would get tensors with the shape of the biggest tensor that entered the batch maybe `(265,50)`....Does anybody have any idea of what i am doing wrong or that i am not specifying for the batching process or any of the above processes ?
Been stuck on this for 5 days :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... first of all i as only putting unique integers to my feature lists instead of "lists of integers" to my example. So the script did not understand why all of a sudden i was looking for 50 component vectors.